# Preventing code duplication between signed and unsigned integers logic

Tags: c

I have the following functions : The first prints unsigned integers in a given base (radix).
The second function does exactly the same but with a signed integers.
As you can see, the body of these functions are exactly the same. I've been struggling for hours in order to prevent doubling the same code, and I could not find a solution for this issue.

**Unsigned function:**

```
const char *digit = "0123456789abcdef";
int print_int_helper_unsigned(unsigned int n, int radix, const char *digit) {

  int result;

  if (n < radix) {

    putchar(digit[n]);

    return 1;
  }
  else {
    result = print_int_helper_unsigned(n / radix, radix, digit);

          putchar(digit[n % radix]);

    return 1 + result;
  }
}
```

**Signed function:**

```
int print_int_helper( int n, int radix, const char *digit) {

  int result;

  if (n < radix) {

    putchar(digit[n]);

    return 1;
  }
  else {
    result = print_int_helper(n / radix, radix, digit);

          putchar(digit[n % radix]);

    return 1 + result;
  }
}
```

Comment: The signed function doesn't actually work with negative values of `n`. Are you aware of that?

Comment: BTW: using recursion here is not good. An iterative approach would be better. And why do you pass `digit``  as parameter?

Comment: What output do you expect for `print_int_helper( -3, 16, digit)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor the recursive part into a helper function:

```
static void fprintf_digits_recursive(FILE *out,
                                     const unsigned long radix,
                                     const char *digits,
                                     unsigned long value)
{
    if (value >= radix)
        fprintf_digits_recursive(out, radix, digits, value / radix);
    fputc(digits[value % radix], out);
}
```

I marked it `static`, because it should only be visible in this compilation unit (file), and not directly callable outside.

The purpose of the helper function is to print out a single digit. If the `value` has more than one digit, the higher digit(s) are printed first. (This is why the `fputc()` is *after* the recursive call.)

Signed and unsigned integer printers use the helper thus:

```
void print_int(const int value, const char *digits, const int radix)
{
    if (radix < 1 || !digits) {
        fprintf(stderr, "print_int(): Invalid radix and/or digits!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (value < 0) {
        fputc('-', stdout);
        fprintf_digits_recursive(stdout, radix, digits, (unsigned long)(-value));
    } else
        fprintf_digits_recursive(stdout, radix, digits, (unsigned long)(value));
}

void print_uint(const unsigned int value, const char *digits, const int radix)
{
    if (radix < 1 || !digits) {
        fprintf(stderr, "print_int(): Invalid radix and/or digits!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fprintf_digits_recursive(stdout, radix, digits, (unsigned long)value);
}
```

I deliberately added the output stream identifier and changed the parameter order, so that it is easier to understand how the visible function (sometimes also called *wrapper functions*, if they're very simple) can differ from the actual internal helper function that does the real work.

I added the radix and digits check to the wrapper functions, because that is the recommended practice. (That is, do not leave parameter checking to the helper functions, but do it in the wrapper functions. That way you can provide also "fast"/unchecked versions of the wrapper functions, if you want.)

This same approach is used to refactor duplicated code into helpers and actual public functions. You find the repeated code, move it to a separate internal helper function, noting that the parameters can be very different than what the public functions use — often, you might have e.g. a dynamically allocated buffer to put the data into.

There is no really hard part, you just need to practice a bit, and learn to think about the multiple users — the originally duplicated functions — when choosing which parameters are passed to the helper function.

In very complicated cases, you might need to split the helper functions into multiple helpers; into a *helper toolbox* of a sort. This is often the case with e.g. dynamic memory management helper functions.

For example, if you wanted to turn this into an interface that produces dynamically allocated strings, you might use a string buffer interface, something like

```
struct strbuffer {
    char   *data;
    size_t  size;   /* Number of chars allocated for */
    size_t  used;   /* Number of chars used in data */
};
#define STRBUFFER_INIT { NULL, 0, 0 }

static void strbuffer_addchar(struct strbuffer *ref, const char c);
static char *strbuffer_finalize(struct strbuffer *ref);
static char *strbuffer_finalize_reverse(struct strbuffer *ref);
```

so that the signed integer-to-string function might look like

```
char *new_int_to_string(const int value, const size_t radix, const char *digits)
{
    struct strbuffer buf = STRBUFFER_INIT;
    if (value < 0) {
        reverse_radix(&buf, radix, digits, -value);
        strbuffer_addchar(&buf, '-');
    } else
        reverse_radix(&buf, radix, digits, value);
    return strbuffer_finalize_reverse(&buf);
}
```

and `reverse_radix()` builds the numeric value in reverse order,

```
void reverse_radix(struct strbuffer *ref,
                   const unsigned long radix,
                   const char *digits,
                   unsigned long value)
{
    do {
        strbuffer_addchar(ref, digits[value % radix]);
        value /= radix;
    } while (value > 0);
}
```

The helper function `strbuffer_finalize()` will reallocate the `data` field to the exact desired length, including a string-terminating `\0`, clear the structure, and return the `data`; `strbuffer_finalize_reverse()` does the same, except reversing the contents first. That way we turn the recursive call into a simple loop, too.

You can even implement a floating-point version using the strbuffer helpers; you just convert the integral part separately from the decimal part (so two more helper functions).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you want this:

```
#include <math.h>
...
int print_int_helper(int n, int radix, const char *digit) {
  if (n < 0)
  {
    putchar('-');
  }

  return print_int_helper_unsigned(abs(n), radix, digit);
}
```

Comment: Umm... you ended up with 2 functions **again** by extracting the repeated code into a function (yes, refactoring is good). Function overload *may* look better in this case from the user of your code point of view. Except this is `C` code, not `C++`... :(

Comment: I really believe there is a way to prevent the repeated code. I marked this answer as a good point been made. But it still not an answer for the main issue. This functions may contain thousands of lines, so doubling the code seems always a bad idea.

Comment: Note that `abs` won't work correctly with `INT_MIN`. To be reliable over complete integer range, you need to handle it separately.

Comment: @user694733 good catch, but as a matter of fact `abs(INT_MIN)` returns `INT_MIN` on most platform and therefore it works in that case, but you are right, it is undefined behaviour.